# How do you find the volume of these two functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the region inside the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 16$ and outside the surface $x^2 + y^2 = 4$.

How would you set this up and solve it using double integration and polar?

I came up with a graph that shows a cylinder in the middle of a sphere. I kind have the idea of subtracting the cylinder volume to the volume of the sphere but I don't know how to set it up, like what would the boundaries be?

Comment: I think I have seen the same question couple of days back ! Not sure if this is homework :P

Comment: Please do not delete your question when it has gotten a good answer. Others can benefit from this thread.

Answer (score 4):

I am adding a picture illustrating all you need to find the volume using cylindrical coordinates.
[image]

In fact; $$V=8\int_{r=2}^{4}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{16-r^2}}rdr d\theta dz$$

Comment: Would I be able to solve it using double integrals?

Comment: Yes. remove the third integral and evaluate $$V=4\int_{r=2}^{4}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}{\sqrt{16-r^2}}rdr d\theta dz$$ instead.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are multiplying by $4$ because of $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Oh yes. How can I make any excuses? Yes. it should have been 8 not 4. I always think positively. :-)

Comment: @FomoLoco: See the last Mhenni's remarking comment.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. :-) and ;-)